# How can I divide existing ARM template (which is exceeding 4mb size standard) to Linked ARM Templates. Is there any tool/scripts for that?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Microsoft Azure has a size restriction for ARM template for deployment it via DevOps CI/CD, the size of the ARM template  can't exceed more than 4mb for direct deployment.

They have provided the solution as to create **Linked template** and deploy it via reference.

[Please Check the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#linked-resource-manager-templates)

[Nested Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#nested-template)

So, Is there any tool/scripts through which we can manually divide the ARM template to Linked ARM Template maintaining all the dependencies?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the template?  Templates that large are pretty rare I'd like to understand your scenario better.  If you don't want to post publicly you can email me (bmoore) at microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, we do not have this tool/scripts to help to divide the ARM template to Linked ARM Template maintaining all the dependencies. We recommend you can create a feedback ticket here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/issues and https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager

Comment: Thanks, I have raised it. So azure must provide a way to convert the same, Otherwise IaaS deployment using ARM would be difficult as it would exceed standard size of 4mb

Comment: Does the answer will help you? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.